# Html search bar value is not being processed in php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to make a search bar that goes through the database and return a table. The value from the form is stored but the php code doesn't return any array of information.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    header("Location:http://127.0.0.1:58199/graduateYearPage.html");
    if (isset($_GET['uni_name']) && is_string($_GET['uni_name'])) {
        $uname = $_GET['uni_name'];
    } else {
        $uname = "";
    }

    $con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'tR60135400', 'db');

    if ($con->connect_errno) {
        echo "We are experiencing problems.";
        exit;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE university = $uname";

    if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
        echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";
        exit;
    }

    if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
        echo "We could not find a match for ID $uname, sorry about that. Please try again.";
        exit;
    } else {
        //OUTPUT A TABLE
        echo "<table> <ul>"
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["firstName"]);
            printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["lastName"]);
            printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["university"]);
        }
        echo "</ul> </table>"
    }
    $result->free();
    $con->close();
    exit;
?>
```

After I get this working this will be a pop up message inside a Bootstrap modal. The table is not working. I also thought that this may be because of the form and how I call the php code.

Here is the html code for the form:

```
<form method="GET" id="search_bar" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="placeholder" type="search" class="form-control" name="uni_name" placeholder=" Enter a university name.">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what are you getting in result ?

Comment: I didn't get any result the only change is seen when the value is typed in nad searched the after the location of the code the value and name is shown: http://127.0.0.1:58199/graduateYearPage.html?uni_name=arizona&submit=

Comment: action should not be blank... it should be your php page and not html page

Comment: <form method="GET" action="server.php" id="search_bar" style="text-align: center;">  Would this be correct? I tried it and it only downloaded the file again.

Comment: In server.php write your searching code . That is php code

Comment: I tried it and it still downloaded the file. I wrote the exact line I have written in the comment before.

Comment: can you paste your whole code here ....r u sing wamp ? lamp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

<kbd>index.html</kbd> or <kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
<form method="GET" id="search_bar" action="search_bar.php" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="placeholder" type="search" class="form-control" name="uni_name" placeholder=" Enter a university name.">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>search_bar.php</kbd>

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]="GET"){
    if(isset($_GET["uni_name"])){
         $uname = $_GET['uni_name'];
    }else{
         $uname = "";
    }
}

$con = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'tR60135400', 'db');

if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "We are experiencing problems.";
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE university = '$uname'";

if (!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
    echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";
    exit;
}

if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    echo "We could not find a match for ID $uname, sorry about that. Please try again.";
    exit;
} else {
    //OUTPUT A TABLE
    echo "<table> <ul>"
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["firstName"]);
        printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["lastName"]);
        printf ("<li>%s</li>", $row["university"]);
    }
    echo "</ul> </table>"
}
$result->free();
$con->close();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: it still did the same thing.. once I write action="server.php" it starts downloading instead of executing the code.

Comment: What's your php version?

Answer (score 0):

in Bootstrap modal you should change in the href tag of the modal opener this tag "data-target=" or remove it because it means modal view mode whether opens a modal view or redirect to a page.
also I notice in your search query a string should be in single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE university = '$uname'
```